# android:shutdown

Tags: shutdown

How can i shutdown my android device pro-grammatically??Till now i have rooted my android device by SuperonClick v.2.3.3.0 and the rooting is successful.Then i have granted my .apk  file superuser permission.Then i have implemented code of executing su file and reboot in my program by

```
try {
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot" });
                DataOutputStream os= new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("/system/bin/-p\n");
                os.flush();     

            } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

.

But the device is not rebooting and is not shutdown.Please help me out..

Comment: The problem is that you use the reboot comand: `"su", "-c", "reboot"`

Comment: Have you tried if the `su -c reboot` command works if you type it in a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)? Or if other commands execute correctly using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the right permissions in the manifest.xml? Something like
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT

EDIT: have you tried just using the su-command?

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Comment: You only need the reboot permission, if you want to reboot the device using the standard Android API. The OP wants to do this with a rooted device on the terminal.

Comment: Thanks I have done with the locking android phone using devicepolicy manager & creating new device admin..